# Can't append new elements to View.el in Backbone.js

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

I am learning the backbone currently, and facing the following problem. 
I want to append new elements to the this.el element of the View. But it doesn't happen. 
here is my code:

```
var MyData = Backbone.Model.extend({
    initialize: function() {
        this.bind('error', function(model, error) {
            console.log('error:' + error);
        });
    },
    defaults: {
        name: "Jo",
        age: 18,
        skill: 0
    },
    validate: function(attributes) {
        if (attributes.name == "Jonh")
            return false;
        return true;
    }
});

var MyView1 = Backbone.View.extend({
    initialize: function() {
        this.$el.empty();
    },
    el: '#middle',
    events: {
        "click": "render"
    },
    render: function() {
        this.$el.append(this.model.get('name'));    
    }
});

var myData = new MyData();
var myView1 = new MyView1( {model: myData} );
```

int the html file there is a div element defined as follows:

```
<div id="middle"></div>
```

The code works without error, but I dont see any appended elements. 
I have also tried to append like this:

```
this.$el.append($("<p>").append(this.model.get('name')));
```

Comment: How do you click on a blank div?

Comment: @haemhweg I clicked to the region, however it was too small
So I tried to call directly the myView1.render(); doesnt work too.

Comment: For testing purposes, I made that #middle div 200px by 200px and gave it a background color so I could see it. I'm not sure why it isn't working for you. I just went through the steps again to make sure and it still works fine for me.

Comment: Put model and view initialize code in $(document).ready(function() { // initialize view and model });

Comment: @maximus http://jsfiddle.net/6ty6B/ works fine for me too. You can check the dependencies here. If it doesn't work for you, surely there must be some error in your console.

Comment: @haemhweg now it works, thanks! :) I have put the code of 
var myData = new MyData();
var myView1 = new MyView1( {model: myData} );
into document ready function

Comment: @haemhweg, can you write your answer to this question so I can mark it as answered?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since your javascript script loads before the page is loaded, Backbone View can't see `#middle` div, so you have to initialize views after page is loaded:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    // load your views
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I just loaded this up in my IDE and it worked fine. You console didn't show you any errors?

Comment: Can you show the libraries you have attached in html file please?
I mean the <script ... backbone-min.js> underscore jquery etc.

Comment: Starting after the content I just have jquery(Google), underscore, backbone, then a script file where I pasted in your code.

Comment: Can you give exact urls to backbone and underescore? Because I had some problems with it when I changed the version, it began to show the errors. I suppose I have an incorrect version

Comment: I just went to both sites and downloaded the latest versions right before I tested it. The latest Develpment version.

Comment: Ok. I try the same way then.